# SVG анимация, перемещение с копированием

Tags: html, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как анимировать такой эффект, перемещая и копируя контур с изменением свойств, что целесообразно использовать для этого?
Чтобы контур копировался перемещаясь по заданному вектору с заданым числом шагов, изменяя свой цвет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 427.4 348"><polyline points="67.6 93.2 349.6 157.2 67.6 215.2 " style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:#EE1F51"/></svg>
```

Comment: плохо понятно какой эффект Вас итересует

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Эффект выдавливания контура по заданному вектору

Comment: найдите пример анимации или изобразите несколько состояний картинками

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Добавил. Можно просто каждый раз вставлять новый код через innerHTML?

Comment: иногда делаю так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если сильно надо именно svg - предлагаю что-то такое:

```js
let i = 0, x = 0, y = 0, dx = 2, dy = 2;
let l1 = document.querySelector('#g1 polyline');
let l2 = document.querySelector('#g2 polyline');
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw() {
  i <10 && requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  i++;
  g1.innerHTML += `<g stroke='hsl(${i*8},55%,55%)' transform=translate(${x},${y})>${l1.outerHTML}<g>`
  g2.innerHTML += `<g stroke='hsl(${i*8},55%,55%)' transform=translate(${x},${y})>${l2.outerHTML}<g>`
}
```

```css
polyline {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 70 427.4 348">
<g id=g1>
  <polyline points="67.6 93.2 349.6 157.2" />
</g>
<g id=g2>
  <polyline points="349.6 157.2 67.6 215.2" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я так и думал, но вы сделали это быстрее, а есть ещё варианты кроме svg?Не webGL же?

Comment: @ПоляковРоман на канве, 2д